# Transform a pseudo left-linear context free Grammer into a left-linear Grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar, automata, finite-automata, formal-languages, formal-methods

So I'm having a small problem.

I've been given the Grammar:

G: A-> Ba_1...a_n
A->a_1...a_n

Now I have to turn this "pseudo" left-linear cf Grammar, into a left-linear cf Grammar.
My idea was to replace a_1...a_n with x, and say x:=a_1...a_n and the new Grammar G' is now:

G': A-> Bx
A->x

Now the cf grammar is a left-linear one. Does this work?
Would really appreciate any help whatsoever.

Comment: Note that it can be a lot more convenient to ask questions about [tag:formal-languages] on [cs.se], where you and your responders can use MathJax to format, rather than futzing around with a limited subset of HTML or leaving the reader to imagine the application of LaTeX. Most formal-languages questions have nothing to do with programming and are therefore outside of SO's scope.

Answer (score 0):

How are you defining "left-linear grammar"? The standard definition, as found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar#Relationship_with_regular_grammars) and many other places is that a left-linear grammar is a context-free grammar in which "all rules are of the form `A → αw` where `α` is either empty or a single nonterminal and `w` is a **string of terminals**". (Emphasis added.)

With that definition, your "pseudo"-left-linear grammar is left-linear as long as `a1…an` contains no non-terminals. If that's not the case, the grammar is not linear and there is no algorithm which can construct a linear grammar from a non-linear grammar. (If there were, regular languages would be the same set as context-free grammars, which is certainly not the case.)

If you (or whoever set you the task) are using a different definition, you should provide it as part of the question.

Regardless, changing the first production to `A → BX` makes the grammar non-linear, so that doesn't seem likely to be the desired answer. (Writing the name of `X` as `x` does not stop it from being a non-terminal. A non-terminal is any symbol for which there is at least one production, so the existence of the `x → ...` production is sufficient to make `x` a non-terminal.)

Furthermore, if the goal is to ensure that all rules have at most two symbols on the right-hand side (vaguely similar to Chomsky Normal Form), then you'll need some kind of recursive application of whatever rule you use